# <list> count is showing Count = 0x00000001

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I am calling a collection using  in aspx code behind using C# VS2008 SP3.5

Why is  count showing Count 0x00000001 instead of 1.

Comment: how are you printing the value?

Comment: Is that in the debugger? Do you have hex display turned on?

Comment: thanks everyone, the Hex display was turned on in the debug.

Answer (score 9):

You really need to be more specific about where this is being shown.

I'll guess that perhaps you are seeing this in the watch window while debugging? If so, you probably have it set to show hex values. Try right clicking in the watch window to uncheck the  hexadecimal option.

0x00000001 is the exact same value as 1, but the first version is in hexadecimal notation, and it shows the full number of digits available, instantly indicating how large (how many bytes) the variable is.

Comment: this fixed it for me. the hexadecimal option that is